# Avoid extra allocations while encoding data as CBOR, using kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, cbor

When using [`kotlinx.serialization`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) and encoding data as JSON, it's possible to write serialized data directly into an `OutputStream`, via `Json.encodeToStream(SerializationStrategy<T>, T, OutputStream)`.

Yet, with [CBOR](https://cbor.io):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-serialization-cbor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

— only writing to or reading from a `ByteArray` (`byte[]` JVM type) seems possible (`Cbor.encodeToByteArray(SerializationStrategy<T>, T): ByteArray`), and the byte array returned gets allocated by the library itself, can't be supplied externally, nor can it be reused.

This leads to extra allocations and frequent `OutOfMemoryError`'s when encoding large data hierarchies as CBOR, which never happens with JSON.

Using `kotlinx.serialization`, how do I encode my data into an `OutputStream` or a pre-allocated `ByteBuffer`?